# Response Delay in react native FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using `<FlatList>` to render a list:

```
  <FlatList

        ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
        refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
        onRefresh={this.doPullRefresh}
        onEndReached={this.endFooter}
        initialNumToRender={10}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
        removeClippedSubviews={false}
        data={this.state.listdata}
        renderItem={({item}) => <ListItem onPress={this.goToStuInfo} alldata={item} id={item.key} number={item.number} avatar={item.avatar} name={item.name} />}
      />
```

The total size of data is about 300. So I can see some data is displayed while other data is being rendered as a list item.

**At this moment(some data is still being rendered),** if I touch an item, there will be a delay. I have to wait for a long time to get the response. And I have to wait even when I press the Back button.

Is there any solution that the list can response my touch movement first?

**My Solution**

Well, I solved this problem by render 10 items once.

I will push more data to `this.state.listdata` in `onEndReached`

Works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are props change when ya touch items ?? 300 list elements not the big deal

"Limiting the render window also reduces the amount of work that needs to be done by React and the native platform, e.g from view traversals. Even if you are rendering the last of a million elements, with these new lists there is no need to iterate through all those elements in order to render. You can even jump to the middle with scrollToIndex without excessive rendering."

Comment: Nope, the item will execute `console.log('item is touched');` when pressed. But I have to wait for a long time to see this message printed on the screen.